# Function that returns true if string contains "xyz" not directly preceeded by a period?

Tags: java, string

I am really confused by a CodingBat Java exercise. It's suppose to return true if the given string contains an appearance of "xyz" where the xyz is not directly preceeded by a period (.). So "xxyz" counts but "x.xyz" does not.

```
xyzThere("abcxyz") → true
xyzThere("abc.xyz") → false
xyzThere("xyz.abc") → true
```

I couldn't figure this out for the life of me so I just looked up a solution online and I'm so confused why this works. Any wanna help clarify? I added some comments on the code as to what I am having trouble with.

```
public boolean xyzThere(String str) { 
int pos =0;
while ((pos = str.indexOf("xyz")) >= 0) { `
```

The `while ((pos = str.indexOf("xyz")) >= 0) {` confuses me here. I tried this without the double brackets and it didn't work. Does the double brackets do some kind of casting to an int or something? Also how does `pos` even get assigned to something in a while statement, does it run the part on the right first then assigns it?

```
if (pos == 0) 
    return true; 
if (str.charAt(pos-1) != '.') 
    return true; // found it 
    // xyz was preceded by a period so skip over this match 
    str = str.substring(pos+1);
```

I am so confused how it can even reach `str = str.substring(pos+1);` I thought I could just take this out entirely but it broke the entire program. Since it's an if statement and it has no brackets to make it a block statement, how or when is this reached, and what is the logic behind it? What the purpose of this statement, as it seems so pointless to me. Even if it does get reached in the code, what does it do?

```
} 

return false; // no luck 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any readers, here's the xyzThere problem: http://codingbat.com/prob/p136594

Since you were initially looking for any solution, here's a non-looping solution:

```
public boolean xyzThere(String str) {
    return str.replaceAll("\\.xyz", "").contains("xyz");
}
```

Regarding double parens: if you remove the double parens, then it won't compile, because the compiler interprets that as trying to assign `str.indexOf("xyz") >= 0` to the `pos` variable, and the types, boolean and int respectively, don't match.

You will notice that assignment is at the bottom of java operator precedence - without the extra parens, it will occur last: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~palsetia/java/precedenceTable.html
unle

Regarding assignment in a loop - yes this is valid.  The value assigned to `pos` is then compared with 0.

Regarding `str = str.substring(pos+1);`. This is how the posted solution is removing ".xyz" from the string which finally determines whether the string still contains "xyz".

Regarding the if statement

```
if (str.charAt(pos-1) != '.') 
return true; // found it
```

Without brackets, the implied scope of the if statement if the next statement. The style here is generally considered back practice for just the reason you've found and should be rewritten as either:

```
if (str.charAt(pos-1) != '.') {
  return true;
}
```

or

```
if (str.charAt(pos-1) != '.') return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while ((pos = str.indexOf("xyz")) >= 0) {
```

`indexOf` returns -1 if the string is not found so this is going to continue looking so long as an "xyz" is found in the string. See later for how it makes sure this is *another* occurrence rather than the same one again.

The extra bracket is to stress that there is also an assignment going on here. `pos` is being updated to the start of the "xyz" that was found (or -1 if no more).

```
if (pos == 0) 
  return true;
```

It is allowed at the start - I guess.

```
if (str.charAt(pos-1) != '.') 
  return true;
```

If there is **not** a "." just before it then we're done.

```
str = str.substring(pos+1);
```

Throw away everything up to and including the "x" of the discovered "xyz". Makes sure that next time around we don't find the same one again.

```
return false;
```

We got to the end without finding one - it must not be there.

Comment: if you would incorporate my clarification with your answer, we'd have something more complete that answers the OP's question more thoroughly, then I can delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet needs "double brackets" (really double parentheses -- it pays to be precise because brackets are a different character) because the parens group different parts of what amounts to a mathematical expression. What you think are double brackets are actually single parens grouping different parts of the expression from what you probably think they're grouping.

```
while ((pos = str.indexOf("xyz")) >= 0)
                         ^-----^
       ^------------------------^
      ^-------------------------------^
```

If you switch to an IDE instead of the simple text editor that you're probably using, the IDE will highlight matching parentheses so you can see which opening paren is related to which closing paren. There's no casting or other magic going on. Parentheses, brackets, angle brackets, and curly braces. are just there to show the beginning and end of particular groups of things, whether it's an expression, an expression within an expression, a data set, etc.